# SQL Server regular expression select and update

Tags: sql, regex, database, sql-server-2008

I have a column that I need to clean the data up on.

First I'd like to do a select to get a record of the bad data then I've like to run a replace on the invalid charters.

I'm looking to select anything that contains non alphanumeric characters but ignores the slash "\" as the second character and also ignores underscores and dashes in the rest of the string. Here's a couple of example of the data I'm expecting to get back from this query.

```
@\AAA
A\Adam's
A\Amanda.Smith
B\Bear's-ltd
C\Couple & More
```

After this I'd like to run a replace on any of these invalid characters and replace them with underscores so the result would look like this:

```
_\AAA
A\Adam_s
A\Amanda_Smith
B\Bear_s-ltd
C\Couple_More
```

Answer (score 1):

I do not think there is native support for that. You can create a CLR to support regex, ex: https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/clr-assembly-regex-functions-for-sql-server-by-example/